# Scan related tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I think we need to sort out the following scan-related tags:

- [scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanner) x 155
- [scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanning) x 87
- [printer-scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-scanner) x 9
- [document-scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/document-scanning) x 5
- <strike>[scan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scan) x 1</strike>

The rest are [barcode-scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/barcode-scanner), [scan-disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scan-disk) and [overscan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/overscan) which are alright and shouldn't be changed.

---

Now, from [scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanning) tag wiki, I understand this is the one that refes to scanning a document/photo/etc using a scanner/printer scanner/etc:

> Converting a physical document into digital form

So if we leave it that way, we need to merge [document-scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/document-scanning) into [scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanning).

---

The [scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanner) tag includes questions about [scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanning), [printer-scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-scanner) and [not-printer-scanner] - so I think that if we leave only [scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanning) and [scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanner) then we should retag some of them questions in [scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanner) and and merge [printer-scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-scanner) into [scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanner), synonymize and add a tag wiki.

Comment: There's also [multifunction](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multifunction), for printer/scanner/fax combined devices.

Comment: Wow, apparently this nest has been around for a while. I just came in to raise this issue, and someone did well over 3 years ago! Some updated numbers: [scanner] 239, [scanning] 144, [printer-scanner] 16, [document-scanning] 16